macos architecture error when building in esp-idf - "frozen runpy"
I am trying to get esp-idf working on a M1 Macbook Air. It installed without errors, but fails when building one of the examples.
I can set the target chip OK in the example, but when I try to build, I get a CMake error:
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done  
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32  
CMake Error at /Users/andrew/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:552 (message):  
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main  

which points to a Macro, so I have no idea what its input is.
      execute_process(COMMAND ${python}  
        "-m"  
        "idf_component_manager.prepare_components"  
        "--project_dir=${project_dir}"  
        "--lock_path=${dependencies_lock_file}"  
        "--interface_version=${component_manager_interface_version}"  
        "prepare_dependencies"
        "--local_components_list_file=${local_components_list_file}"  
        "--managed_components_list_file=${managed_components_list_file}"  
        RESULT_VARIABLE result  
        ERROR_VARIABLE error)  
    
        if(NOT result EQUAL 0)  
          message(FATAL_ERROR "${error}")  
        endif()  

Within the long error message, there is repeated a few times
   mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')

This seems to be after a failed import -
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/andrew/.espressif/python_env/idf5.3_py3.12_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic_core/_pydantic_core.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002):

That file exists, but is a 4MB document file containing all sorts of characters with no recognizable beginning to the file.
I have successfully installed esp-idf on a M1 Mac Mini, and followed the same steps for the MBA. This is the final test step.
For reference, CMake is the latest version 3.31.1 and was installed before esp-idf.  Python is version 3.12 (the only version on the MBA). CMake, Python, VSCode have all been cleanly re-installed.
Any ideas/pointers?

Hi! A question post (and its title) is not the place where one may describe his/her state. If you think that your question won't be useful for anyone, then you could delete the question. If you are not sure about question's usefulness, then just leave the question as is. Stack Overflow has the automatic mechanism for cleanup questions which prove themselves as not useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

Thank you @Tsyvarev. I didn't realise I could actually delete the question. Now that there is a reply on it (yours), it would probably not be a good idea to delete it.  I am used to questions generating a discussion with the OP, often asking for clarification of some aspect, and I didn't want anyone expecting me to reply. There hadn't been many views, so I thought it was not of interest to others. I had not been able to find any related questions in the internet, so thought it was not a common area of concern.

"Now that there is a reply on it (yours), it would probably not be a good idea to delete it." - Not quite true. The only "reply" which technically prevents a question to be deleted is an answer post. Sometimes comments contain useful information about the problem asked in the question. However, in the given case my comments aren't related with the problem: they are only about the form of the question and your experience on Stack Overflow. That is, feel free to delete the question if you want. Just tend to not not delete many of your questions.
